# Directive with click listener and click event on the same element in Angular2

Tags: angular

```
<a appMenuDropDown (click)="getSubMenuItems(menuItem)">
.......
</a>
```

What happens when an element has a directive (appMenuDropDown) listening for a click event and a click event handler (getSubMenuItems()) ? Which handler gets triggered first ? Handler in directive or getSubMenuItems() ?

```
@HostListener('click')
clickListener() {
    let sourceElement = this.el.nativeElement;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I think element's event will be fired first. You can simply `console.log` both and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in your case HostListener within directive will be always fired first

You can take a look at `generateHandleEventMethod` method within compiler from source code

```
directives.forEach((dirAst, dirIdx) => {
  ...
});
boundEvents.forEach((renderEvent, renderEventIdx) => {
  ...
});
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.2.4/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/event_binder.ts#L92-L115

and here is generated component.ngfactory

```
View_AppComponent0.prototype.handleEvent_4 = function(eventName,$event) {
  var self = this;
  self.debug(4,2,4);
  self.markPathToRootAsCheckOnce();
  var result = true;
  result = (self._AppMenuDropDownDirective_4_3.handleEvent(eventName,$event) && result);
  if ((eventName == 'click')) {
    var pd_sub_0 = (self.context.getSubMenuItems() !== false);
    result = (pd_sub_0 && result);
  }
  return result;
};
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/eI5PXu5w9AW5CWBYMR9e?p=preview)**

Comment: It is indeed directive handler first in all my testing. I was not sure if it is programmed to be in that specific order. Thank you for the demo and the compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

The order of event handlers is explicitly undefined. 
Also if you have several directives on an element, the order they are added is not significant to the order event handlers are processed.